# how to know APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID and YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN of my web application

Tags: dns, angular6, auth0, clientid

I have created a web application following this guide https://auth0.com/blog/creating-beautiful-apps-with-angular-material/.

In the guide, they create auth0.ts file.

There, they mentioned setting my APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID and  YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN.

I don't understand where to get these IDs from.

Here is the code for my `auth.ts` file.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as auth0 from 'auth0-js';

(window as any).global = window;

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    clientID: '<APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID>',
    domain: '<YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN>',
    responseType: 'token',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    scope: 'openid'
  });
  accessToken: String;
  expiresAt: Number;

  constructor(public router: Router) { }

  public login(): void {
    this.auth0.authorize();
  }
  public handleAuthentication(): void {
    this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken) {
        window.location.hash = '';
        this.accessToken = authResult.accessToken;
        this.expiresAt = (authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + new Date().getTime();
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      } else if (err) {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        console.log(err);
      }
    });

  }
  public logout(): void {
    this.accessToken = null;
    this.expiresAt = null;

    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return new Date().getTime() < this.expiresAt;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you signed up for Auth0 and created an application.

If you go to your [Application Dashboard](https://manage.auth0.com/#/applications) you'll see your app listed.

Click on the application's name and you'll enter the application settings page. The little icons on the right let you copy the information you need.

[image: application settings]

If you haven't signed up, you can [sign up](https://auth0.com/signup) for free.

Once logged in and you need to create a new application, click on "+ New Application". From here you can follow the built-in guide to create a **Single-Page Application** inside Auth0.

[image: SPA button]

Once you've created your application, you can copy the aforementioned configuration into the `auth.ts` file.

If you were to copy the settings from my screenshot, your `auth.ts` file would look like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as auth0 from 'auth0-js';

(window as any).global = window;

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    clientID: 'c45ij324tg345bjnfojo2u6b4352',
    domain: 'your-auth0-domain.auth0.com',
    responseType: 'token',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    scope: 'openid'
  });
  accessToken: String;
  expiresAt: Number;

  constructor(public router: Router) { }

  public login(): void {
    this.auth0.authorize();
  }
  public handleAuthentication(): void {
    this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken) {
        window.location.hash = '';
        this.accessToken = authResult.accessToken;
        this.expiresAt = (authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + new Date().getTime();
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      } else if (err) {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        console.log(err);
      }
    });

  }
  public logout(): void {
    this.accessToken = null;
    this.expiresAt = null;

    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return new Date().getTime() < this.expiresAt;
  }
}
```

Disclosure: I work for Auth0.

Comment: perfect explanation.